# Run-time error in VBA Macro

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to split a file into sets of lines. I want it to break approximately every 2000 lines, but if the email address (in column AD) is a common value between the last line and the following line, get all of the lines with that same value before splitting.

So far, I have the following:

```
Sub Chunkify_Data()
    Dim inputFile As String, inputWb As Workbook
        Dim lastRow As Long, srow As Long, erow As Long
        Dim newFile As Workbook
        Dim etext As String, netext As String


    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
        lastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row

        Set newFile = Workbooks.Add


        srow = 1805
        While erow < lastRow
            erow = srow + 1999
            If (erow > lastRow) Then
                erow = lastRow
            Else
                etext = ActiveSheet.Cells(erow, 30).Value
                netext = ActiveSheet.Cells(erow + 1, 30).Value
                'Don't split up emails
                While (StrComp(etext, netext, vbTextCompare) = 0)
                    erow = erow + 1
                    netext = ActiveSheet.Cells(erow + 1, 30).Value
                Wend
            End If

            .Rows(1).EntireRow.Copy newFile.Worksheets(1).Range("A1")
            .Rows(srow & ":" & erow).EntireRow.Copy newFile.Worksheets(1).Range("A2")

            'Save in same folder as input workbook with .xlsx
            newFile.SaveAs Filename:=srow & "-" & erow & ".xlsx", CreateBackup:=False
            srow = erow + 1
        Wend
    End With

    newFile.Close saveChanges:=False
End Sub
```

The second netext = line fails with "Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error". I can't work out why. Any ideas?

Comment: What is the error given?

Comment: Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error. Added to the Question.

Comment: The while does not end and it goes to the end of the page and when erow = the last row on the sheet it cannot go any further and you get the error.

Comment: /facepalm

Of course. I caught it in the outer while, but not the inner one. Thank you! Make it an answer and I'll upvote you, otherwise I'll do it myself.

Comment: Yup, not errorring now. Still not working, but that error is solved.